# Is there a maximum number of documentRefs which can be passed into firestore.getAll()

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, sdk

In the Google SDK Documentation, the [firestore.getAll()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#getAll) command takes [document reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html)s and returns an array of [document snapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html)s from the datastore.

I haven't found any maximums for the number of `documentRefs` which can be passed in. We have tested this successfully with 420 documents, but don't have any larger queries in our test environments and would like to validate the maximum (if any) prior to releasing to production.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Why did you remove the `sdk` tag? The question involves usage of the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The query would just take more time to resolve depending on number of documents.

Comment: Are you sure though? I would hate to get this in production have 1000 documents get passed in and things blow up. E.g. batch writes have a max of 500 (though I guess it is documented under the batch docs).

Comment: @Brettski I've used that with ~7500 documents (that works fine).

Comment: Nothing like live proof. Thank you, I appreciate your response.

Comment: @brettski -- If you suspect that your system could have 1000 documents passed in production, then I encourage you to load test your system at that scale. While the Firestore method may work with 1000 documents, that doesn't mean that your application will.

Comment: Thank you @DazWilkin, that is a really good point and I am glad you put it here. We have tested our application with 4500 documents in production using our current Promise.all() method, so it "should" be good :) Once added to production we'l test these again.